# Would this be a ideal way to setup a database?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

Haven't finished some of the relationships, sort of confused on that end of things.

Would `follows` be a many to one relationship since a customer can follow many merchants but a merchant can't follow a customer?

[image]

Comment: One customer can follow many merchants and one merchant can be followed by many customers, which makes it a many-to-many relationship. But `user_id` should then be `customer_id` (and reference the `id` of `customer`) in your `follows` table.

Comment: gotcha, makes sense. like this? https://imgur.com/puZhHWF I also assume I should make `user_id` into `customer_id` for `likes` and `orders` table too.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be many-many since multiple customers can follow merchants each merchant is related to multiple customers. To **normalize** this relation you would create a new table - call it customer_merchants or something like that. This has just two columns, a customer_id and a merchant_id.

Each time you have a customer following a merchant you create a new row in customer_merchant to reflect that fact.

Now you have a 1-many relation between customers and customer_merchants and a 1-many relation between merchants and customer_merchants.

Here is a webpage about database normalization that might help you understand more :-

https://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic has-many-through relationship.

- Customer has many follows
- Customer has many merchants through follows
- Merchant has many follows
- Merchant has many customers through follows

Because the relationship is between different models (i.e., a customer can't follow another customer) you don't have to construct a polymorphic table; it's enough to have "follows" as a join.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that I may not have fully understood the meaning of all of your design so I used what I could to make this design in 5th normal form.

I took the view that customers, users and merchants are all people playing roles.
For example, one of the semantic clues is that "Gender" is a property of a person not of a thing called a "user". (A "user" is a role played by a person)

Another good practice is to store all address data in one table.
Each of the roles (customers, users and merchants) is linked to the address table by using PK-FK relationships with the "Person" table.

I made the assumption that one product can have many variants which is why the variants have their own table.

The SQL DDL is based on T-SQL (Sorry, I don't speak PostGres but [this wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL) should help with that)

So here are two artefacts: A logical model in fifth normal form and the SQL DDL for that logical model.

[image: The logical model diagram]

**The SQL DDL**

```
    CREATE SCHEMA Orders
GO

CREATE TABLE Orders.Person
(
    personNr int NOT NULL,
    addressNr int NOT NULL,
    firstName nchar(30) NOT NULL,
    gender nchar(6) NOT NULL,
    lastName nchar(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Person_PK PRIMARY KEY(personNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Orders.Address
(
    addressNr int NOT NULL,
    city nchar(50) NOT NULL,
    countryCode nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    postalCode nchar(12) NOT NULL,
    street nchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Address_PK PRIMARY KEY(addressNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Orders.Customer
(
    customerNr int NOT NULL,
    orderNr int NOT NULL,
    stripeID nchar(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Customer_PK PRIMARY KEY(customerNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Orders.Merchant
(
    merchantNr int NOT NULL,
    creationDate datetime NOT NULL,
    merchantName nchar(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Merchant_PK PRIMARY KEY(merchantNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Orders."User"
(
    userNr int NOT NULL,
    email nchar(50) NOT NULL,
    password nchar(50) NOT NULL,
    userName nchar(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT User_PK PRIMARY KEY(userNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Orders."Order"
(
    orderNr int NOT NULL,
    orderDate datetime NOT NULL,
    orderStatus nchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Order_PK PRIMARY KEY(orderNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Orders.Product
(
    productNr int NOT NULL,
    createdDate datetime NOT NULL,
    productName nchar(40) NOT NULL,
    productStatus nchar(10) NOT NULL,
    unitPrice decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Product_PK PRIMARY KEY(productNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Orders.OrderHasProductInQuantity
(
    orderNr int NOT NULL,
    productNr int NOT NULL,
    quantity smallint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT OrderHasProductInQuantity_PK PRIMARY KEY(orderNr, productNr, quantity)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Orders.Variant
(
    variantNr int NOT NULL,
    imageURL nchar(200) NOT NULL,
    title nchar(20) NOT NULL,
    variantPrice decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Variant_PK PRIMARY KEY(variantNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Orders.PersonLikesProduct
(
    personNr int NOT NULL,
    productNr int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PersonLikesProduct_PK PRIMARY KEY(personNr, productNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Orders.PersonFollowsMerchant
(
    merchantNr int NOT NULL,
    personNr int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PersonFollowsMerchant_PK PRIMARY KEY(personNr, merchantNr)
)
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders.Person ADD CONSTRAINT Person_FK FOREIGN KEY (addressNr) REFERENCES Orders.Address (addressNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders.Customer ADD CONSTRAINT Customer_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (orderNr) REFERENCES Orders."Order" (orderNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders.Customer ADD CONSTRAINT Customer_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (customerNr) REFERENCES Orders.Person (personNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders.Merchant ADD CONSTRAINT Merchant_FK FOREIGN KEY (merchantNr) REFERENCES Orders.Person (personNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders."User" ADD CONSTRAINT User_FK FOREIGN KEY (userNr) REFERENCES Orders.Person (personNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders.OrderHasProductInQuantity ADD CONSTRAINT OrderHasProductInQuantity_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (orderNr) REFERENCES Orders."Order" (orderNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders.OrderHasProductInQuantity ADD CONSTRAINT OrderHasProductInQuantity_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (productNr) REFERENCES Orders.Product (productNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders.Variant ADD CONSTRAINT Variant_FK FOREIGN KEY (variantNr) REFERENCES Orders.Product (productNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders.PersonLikesProduct ADD CONSTRAINT PersonLikesProduct_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (personNr) REFERENCES Orders.Person (personNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders.PersonLikesProduct ADD CONSTRAINT PersonLikesProduct_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (productNr) REFERENCES Orders.Product (productNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders.PersonFollowsMerchant ADD CONSTRAINT PersonFollowsMerchant_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (personNr) REFERENCES Orders.Person (personNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO


ALTER TABLE Orders.PersonFollowsMerchant ADD CONSTRAINT PersonFollowsMerchant_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (merchantNr) REFERENCES Orders.Merchant (merchantNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO
```